# Convert txt file to a dictionary in python

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to read a txt file and convert it to a dictionary in python, the txt file has list of countries with their per capita income e.g "Quatar  $129,700 Monaco  $78,700,,,," when I tried to solve the problem the out put I am getting is " 'Quatar  $129': 700 " I could not figure out why?

````
with open("dict.txt") as file:
for line in file:
    (key, val) = line.split()
    dictionary[int(key)] = val

print (dictionary)```
````

Comment: In your posted example, you should split by either spaces or `$`... `line.split("$")`... What is happening is that it looks like your split is using commas. I can provide an example if you need past that

Comment: change `file` variable to something else besides overwriting a python built-in keyword, and use `dictionary[key] = val`, then your code appears to work as expected. Produces output: `{'Quatar': '$129,700', 'Monaco': '$78,700'}` See demo: https://repl.it/@downshift/DutifulBadAmpersand

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dictionary = {}

with open("dict.txt") as file:
for line in file:
    (key, val) = line.split()
    dictionary[key] = val
```

if you are looking to have the values as decimals you can strip off the "$" and cast it into an decimal by doing something like this

```
from decimal import Decimal
from re import sub

dictionary = {}

with open("dict.txt") as file:
for line in file:
    (key, val) = line.split()
    dictionary[key] = Decimal(sub(r'[^\d.]', '', val))
```

Answer (score 3):

In your case:

```py
with open("dict.txt") as file:
    for line in file.readlines():     # readlines should split by '/n' for you
        (key, val) = line.split(' ')  # change delimiter to space, not default "," delimited
        dictionary[int(key)] = val  
print (dictionary)
```

Generally, I would recommend to use the [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) class in the built-in 'csv' module